# Flutter FutureBuilder hasData and connectionState

Tags: flutter, future

The article [Fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) shows the following snippet of code for [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to process the `snapshot`.

```
FutureBuilder<Post>(
  future: post,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.title);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

This just doesn't seem quite solid enough. Couldn't there be cases when `snapshot.connectionState` is `ConnectionState.done` but both `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.hasError` are both `false`? A future can legitimately return `null` as its result. The snippet above would then incorrectly show the loading indicator indefinitely, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`snapshot.hasData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html)

> Returns whether this snapshot contains a non-null data value.
>
> This can be false even when the asynchronous computation has completed successfully, if the computation did not return a non-null value. For example, a Future will complete with the null value even if it completes successfully.

Thus, `snapshot.hasData` will return false on null value reception, confirming your thoughts in your question.

[`snapshot.hasError`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasError.html)

> Returns whether this snapshot contains a non-null error value.
>
> This is always true if the asynchronous computation's last result was failure.

A non-null error value is gotten when the server responds with a status that indicates a failure such a 404, 500 with an [error object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/error.html) accompanying the snapshot or whatever is returned from the operation

`snapshot.hasError` will be false on a failed request or a case where the request was never even made (in the case of no network or poor network) and the response has a non-null value (there will be an [error object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/error.html) attached to the snapshot on `ConnectionState.DONE` being true; i.e on completion),

`snapshot.hasData` being false means that `ConnectionState.DONE` is true and `snapshot.hasData` is `null` (including cases where the expected result of the operation is of type `void`)

The answer to your question depends on whether an [error object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/error.html) was attached to the response from the server or not when the request is erroneous because of something that occurred on the server side. There'll always be an error object attached to the response if the request failed because it was never made because of bad network.

If the error object is null, then the LoadingIndicator will display indefinitely